# jPlayer is not working properly on iOS iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, css, jplayer

I'd like to set up jplayer for iphone and I don't see why it's not working on iPhone
I read all topics about jplayer and mobile devices and I found out that iPhone support *.m4v as movie files.

So I did m4v, webm, ogv

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "http://revelier.home.pl/odszkodowania/video/o-nas.m4v",
            ogv: "http://revelier.home.pl/odszkodowania/video/o-nas.ogv",
            webmv: "http://revelier.home.pl/odszkodowania/video/o-nas.webm",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "m4v, webm, ogv",
    size: {
        width: "640px",
        height: "750px",
        cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
    },
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

**Example source:**
[Example on external server](http://revelier.home.pl/odszkodowania/source/jQuery/demo-01-video-bm.htm)

Please anyone who's using iOS, iPhone or iPad could help me why it is not working properly as it should?

**Notice**: working on all major browsers on Win7 32bit ( Opera, Chrome, IE, Firefox, Maxthon, Safari ) also works on android 4.0.2 ( Opera Classic, Chrome, default andoid browser ).

Any Help would be appreciate.

Comment: I have just entered the link you provided on my iPhone 4S and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm thats weird hope thats going well on all iPhone's. My friend checked it and supposedly it didnt worked. But well maybe she did something wrong and I want too have sure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
stalled: function(event) { 
    $scope.ObjID.jPlayer("playHead",$scope.currentPlayerPosition); 
    $scope.disableEnablePlay('simple','enable'); 
},
suspend: function(event) { 
    $scope.ObjID.jPlayer("playHead",$scope.currentPlayerPosition); 
    $scope.disableEnablePlay('simple','enable'); 
}
```

Comment: please look at [answer]